# Creating climate maps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography, weather, big-data

I have millions of points having temperature and humidity information covering the Middle East and North Africa (MENA).

How can I create animated heatmaps/hotspot maps of change over time? The data have a time and date field. I would like to do this using QGIS, either version 3.2.2 or 2.18.

An example of what I am trying to accomplish: https://www.climate.gov/maps-data.

Comment: You have briefly described your challenge but what have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I just need a guidelines the best tools in QGIS to create animation heatmap for Temperature and Humidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in order to get a kind of heatmap from your points you could use interpolation, maybe TIN (https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html).

And for animation there is this nice plugin https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager. However it may not support raster output from interpolation, i never used it this way, so you'll have to convert it in vector or generate contour lines.